# Bicycle helmet and backpack as carry-on in the US?

Tags: air-travel, usa, airport-security, hand-luggage, fragile-luggage

I'd like to fly somewhere for a weekend bicycle ride.  Is it possible to attach my bike helmet to a small backpack (one of those used for a 2L water pouch) and call it a carry-on?  (The bike itself is already at the destination.)

Comment: Push bike or motorbike? Either way it should be fine.

Comment: I have flown with my bicycle helmet clipped my carry on pack in the past, it is essentially a hat.  But ultimately it will depend on which airline and the gate agent.

Comment: Worst case scenario, I could always put it on my head.  "It makes me feel safer when flying.  You don't want me to get all anxious and crazy, do you?"  :-)

Comment: Are you afraid about airport security not allowing it or the airline charging extra?

Comment: With a 2L bag, you could just put both backpack and helmet in a plastic bag and nobody would notice anyway. Not unless you've got 4 other carry on bags anyway.

Comment: @JoErNanO Either.  I just don't want to get surprised and end up at my destination without a helmet because I couldn't take it with me for whatever reason.  If the airline decided to charge me another $20 but still let me bring it on, then that's fine too.  But, if they wanted me to put it in as checked luggage and I was already at the gate... then I'm out of luck, right?

Comment: Wouldn’t one get into potential hassle with the 2 l water pouch? I mean, it *is* an empty liquid container …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an airport security standpoint I think the helmet should cause no problems in your carry-on. The TSA prohibited item search tool does not mention bicycle helmets. [It does however mention all other types of helmets](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=helmet) including motorcycle helmets, which are considerably tougher than bicycle helmets and can be used as an offensive weapon. Interestingly enough, TSA says that motorbike helmets are allowed in carry-on luggage:

> [image: TSA allows motorbike helmets in carry-on]

The same is also true for other, arguably more potentially dangerous and heavy, helmets including football helmet, welding helmet, lacrosse helmet, etc. Therefore **it is safe to assume that bicycle helmets are allowed too**.

Now, in terms of carry-on luggage allowance, I think you will be fine. For starters, the combined volume of your small backpack with the helmet attached will most probably be comprised within your maximum allowance. Moreover, I have flown with items strapped to my carry-on backpack multiple times and was never questioned. If worse comes to worse, either jam the helmet inside the backpack, wear it, hang it from your trousers and call it a keychain, or do something so that it does not appear to be part of your carry-on.

Answer (score 4):

I have done this many times with a standard roll-away suitcase. I see no reason that a backpack would be different. I have always joked that if anyone hassles me, I will *wear* the helmet, and say I have fear of flying.